# handling 'wrong' entries and NAs in a data.table substituting them with entries from other table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I am using data.table in the context of a wider application using shiny and [handsontable.js](http://handsontable.com/). This is the flow of this part of the app:

1. I publish a data.table on the browser with numeric columns using handsontable & shiny. This is rendered on the screen.
2. The user changes values and each time this happens a new data.table is returned with the data.

The problem is with error management, specifically if an user accidentally keys a character.

My objective is to correct the user's error replacing the single cell value where the character was entered with the value in the original copy (only this cell as the others may contain valid changes to be saved at a later stage in the app).

Sadly I am not able to find an efficient solution to this problem. This is my code and a reproducible sample:

```
# I generate a sample datatable
originTable = data.table( Cat = LETTERS[1:5],
Jan=1:5,
Feb=sample(1:5),
Mar=sample(1:5),
Apr=sample(1:5),
May=sample(1:5))

# I take a full copy & to simulate the effect of a character key in by mistake I convert
# the entire column to character
dt_ <- copy(originTable)
dt_[,Jan := as.character(Jan)]

# "q" entered by mistake by the user - 
dt_[[5,2]] <- "q"

# This is what I get back:
   Cat Jan Feb Mar Apr May
1:   A   1   1   2   4   4
2:   B   2   5   4   2   2
3:   C   3   4   3   1   5
4:   D   4   3   5   5   1
5:   E   q   2   1   3   3
```

Now to my code to try to fix this:

```
valCols <- month.abb[1:5]
for (j in  valCols)
      set(dt_,  
        i = NULL,
        j = j, 
        value= as.numeric(as.character(dt_[[j]])))
```

This gives me a data.table with a NA value somewhere (in place of the character entered by mistake - in a position I ignore).

To substitute the value I've used the following code

```
for (j in  valCols)
   set(dt_,  
    i = which(is.na(dt_[[j]])),
    j = j, 
    value= as.numeric(originTable[[j]]))
```

But it does not work: it finds the correct column, but ignores the `i` value and copies the value contained in `originTable[1,j]` rather than `originTable[i,j]`. In the example dt_[5,2] will get 1 (positioned as originTable[1,2] instead of 5.

In other words I would have expect to see `as.numeric(originTable[[j]])` subsetted by `i` (implicitly) and by `j` (explicitly).
To be fair the Warning is telling me what is happening:

```
Warning message:
In set(dt_, i = which(is.na(dt_[[j]])), j = j, value = as.numeric(originTable[[j]])) :
  Supplied 5 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'Jan' (4 unused)
```

But I remain with my problem unsolved.

I have read countless of apparently similar SO posts but sadly to no avail (possibly because NA handling has evolved in recent releases and older answers do not fully reflect best practice any more). Also a non-NA based solution would be equally acceptable. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you isolate just the data.table part you've an issue with (without all the other details) with *a small reproducible example* and what code of yours isn't working / what the error is etc..

Comment: @Arun added a small reproducible example etc. I hope it is clearer. Thanks E

Comment: @Arun & @Matt_Dowle I am a data.table fan. While I'm satisfied by @eddi's answer, I believe it would be great if data.table at some point in the future would allow an (explicit) i, j syntax. E.g.for the example above `set(dt_,i = which(is.na(dt_[[j]])), j = j, value= as.numeric(originTable[[i,j]]))` which currently gives error.

Comment: @Enzo `data.table` syntax does allow that. The problem in your expression in the OP is that you attempt to assign the entire vector to a single cell. It can work if in your loop you modified `..., value = as.numeric(originTable[[j]][which(is.na(dt_[[j]]))])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# use your criteria to determine what the incorrect values are in each column
wrongs = lapply(dt_[, !"Cat"], function(x) which(is.na(as.numeric(x))))

# now substitute
for (n in names(wrongs)) dt_[wrongs[[n]], (n) := originTable[[n]][wrongs[[n]]]]

dt_
#   Cat Jan Feb Mar Apr May
#1:   A   1   2   5   2   4
#2:   B   2   4   3   4   5
#3:   C   3   3   2   5   2
#4:   D   4   1   1   1   1
#5:   E   5   5   4   3   3
```